# Building a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I need to create a SPARQL query that gives me all the TopicItems contained in a Topic, in the following schema, but I don't know how to do that.
[image]

There is an inverse ObjectProperty named "ContainedIn", I think I must use it, but I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use any inverse property, as you can place SPARQL variables in any position in a triple pattern. Just supply a variable for the object in your triple pattern:

```
SELECT ?topicItem
WHERE {
    <...> slo:consistsOf ?topicItem .
}
```

where `<...>` needs to be replaced with the IRI of the topic you want to examine.

EDIT: I have omitted the prefix declaration here; as you were already using the prefix `slo`, I presumed you had already successfully declared it somehow. Of course, a prefix declaration needs to be added unless the SPARQL endpoint somehow knows `slo` as a pre-defined prefix.

Comment: Something like this? 'PREFIX slo: <http://localhost:8080/OntoSakaiWS/SakaiLanguageOnt.owl#>                  
                     SELECT ?x  
                     WHERE {
 http://localhost:8080/OntoSakaiWS/SakaiLanguageOnt.owl#DBA_ADMIN_TEST_LLLL slo:consistsOf ?x
                        
    
 
                         
                        }'


It returns an error